# For R data.table, how to use uniqueN() in order count unique/distinct values in multiple columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, unique

Let's say we have the following R `data.table` (though a `dataframe` is fine in principle as well):

```
library(data.table)
new_dt = as.data.table(readcsv(...))
head(new_dt)
    name order_no  overlimit
1    Amy       32  TRUE
2   Jack       14  TRUE
3   Jack       16  TRUE
4   Dave       11  FALSE
5    Amy       22  TRUE
6   Jack       16  TRUE
7    Tom       19  FALSE
8  Larry       22  FALSE
9    Tom       89  FALSE
10  Dave       81  TRUE
11  Jack       67  TRUE
12   Tom       60  TRUE
13   Amy       23  FALSE
14  Jack       16  TRUE
```

For this task, the values of `order_no` is irrelevant---I would like to count the unique number of rows for `name` and `overlimit`:

```
name    overlimit  distinct_groups
Amy     TRUE       2
Amy     FALSE      1
Jack    TRUE       4
Jack    FALSE      0
Dave    TRUE       1
Dave    FALSE      1
...
```

Does one simply include more columns in the `by` argument?

Comment: If you want to edit to improve it, I'd say: make it so this can be run by others in a newly opened R console by copy-pasting to make the input; and make sure the desired output shown is complete and corresponds to the input. Anyway, does the linked question not cover it?

Comment: @Frank Yes, I am trying to delete this question. Thank you

Comment: Hm, I think you should be able to delete it now (using a link at the bottom). I can undupe it if you think that would help.

Comment: @Frank There is a slight difference though. Using the solution provided at the URL, `setkey(dt,sex,fruit)[CJ(unique(sex), unique(fruit)), .N, by=.EACHI]`, this would delete any other column in `dt`. Is there a way to keep all of the columns? Naturally, you could use this output and merge with the original data.table, but there may be a better way. 

Am I being clear?

Comment: No, I don't follow. I think your data is probably malformed (seeing repeated values like this). You might want to have a look at hadley's tidy data paper to see how to split it into a few tables https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, you can just add both columns to the `by` argument:

```
dt[, .(distinct_groups = uniqueN(order_no)), by = c("Name", "Overlimit")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the request is to have the adjacent elements in 'overlimit' as a separate group, then we can use `rleid` to create the group

```
dt[, .(overlimit = overlimit[1], distinct_group = uniqueN(order_no)),
     .(name, grp = rleid(overlimit))][, grp := NULL][]
```

---

If it is a simple grouping and wants only combinations

```
dt[, .(distinct_group = .N), by = .(name, overlimit)
  ][CJ(name = dt$name, overlimit = dt$overlimit, unique = TRUE), 
      on = .(name, overlimit)][is.na(distinct_group), distinct_group := 0][]
```

Comment: OP's desired output has zeros in the distinct_groups column; does yours?

Comment: @Frank  I think his input and output are not correct

Comment: @Frank Based on the input example, `Jack TRUE` count is only 3

Comment: Yeah, OP also earned my downvote with a nonreproducible, incomplete and somewhat poorly worded example, fwiw. But I'll keep my downvote on these two answers as well, since y'all did not bother to clarify what the OP wanted before posting. In my opinion, it's very likely they are after the answers in the dupe target.

Comment: @Frank I'm happy to edit.

Comment: @akrun I count `Jack TRUE` to be 4. Rows 2, 3, 11, 14

Comment: @ShanZhengYang  Please go ahead and edit your post with a reproducible example and expected output that matches

Comment: @ShanZhengYang  If you check there are two 16 values for Jack

Comment: @akrun I was being confusing. Forget `order_no`. I am simply trying to count the unique number of rows with `Jack` and `TRUE`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang  Now, I get 5 for Jack and TRUE, updated the post